# Azure AD group provisioning: not getting PATCH request from AD when updating the group

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

We are trying to achieve group sso integration in our application through Azure AD, we are following below link for adding group provisioning functionality 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#step-3-build-a-scim-endpoint
In above link from group operation we have configured all the endpoints as document suggested, what we are able to do is 
1) Create group in our app from AD 
2) Add new users (just created new) in group 
3) Delete group 
But we are struggling to achieve below functionality from AD 
1) Assigning membership to user 
2) remove member from group 
So whenever we are adding any users who are available in users list in our group under membership as "direct members" or whenever we are removing any member from group we are not getting any PATCH (which ideally has to be there as per document) request, I have checked audit log in provisioning and provisioning log, I marked that whenever above both events occur in cycle there is no logs in system it means no event is fired from Azure. 
Its quite crucial thing to have add & remove user from group functionality in SSO but I am unable to find anything even I have configured everything right as per documentation. 
 For more information we have enabled groups mapping in provisioning and also we have create, update, delete enabled in mapping as per image 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#step-3-build-a-scim-endpoint
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a regression introduced in our service around the time that you posted about this that may have lead to the changes not being processed properly. If this is still occurring today, I would suggest opening a support case with Microsoft via portal.azure.com.